# How do i create a labeled Separator?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

edit: Since it seems to be unclear: I want a normal JavaFx Separator (like in the second picture below), but with text **on** it. Here's an example how it looks like in Swing (altough i **don't** want to put a whole box around something!):

[image]

This seems like something that should really be simple, but the the Separator class that JavaFX comes with can't be labeled. Result should look something like the "general options" or "specific options" in this:

[image]

I found http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/2013/01/02/creating-custom-menu-separator-in-javafx/ and tried to apply that to the normal Separator, but since you can't set content at all for that one it didn't work (and you can't use the MenuItemSeparator in other GUI parts then Menu). The shown Options will be a Tab in a TabPane.

Any ideas on how to do this? :)

**SOLUTION**:

```
HBox labeledSeparator = new HBox();
Label label = new Label(text);
Separator leftSeparator = new Separator();
Separator rightSeparator = new Separator();
labeledSeparator.getChildren().add(leftSeparator);
labeledSeparator.getChildren().add(label);
labeledSeparator.getChildren().add(rightSeparator);
labeledSeparator.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an AnchorPane that holds a Separator and a Label? The Separator needs to be anchored to the sides of the AnchorPane while the Label can be anchored at an offset to the left side, say around 20.0. Then, make the background of the Label match the background of your program so the portion of the Separator obscured by the Label is not visible.

Comment: Do let us know if that works. Also, I noticed a drop down arrow on your labeled Separator. If you want that there, there are a number of different approaches to achieve that, including adding a button next to the Label or using a ComboBox instead of a Label.

Comment: Mhm that seems to kinda work, but the Seperator actually obscures the Label and not the other way around.

edit: `label.toFront()` fixed that!

now i have to get the coloring thing right. But thanks for the good suggestion so far! :)

Comment: Instead of doing that, just add the Label last and the Separator first (as children to the AnchorPane).

Comment: I thought it might be better to add two Seperators (one on each side of the label) to avoid all the color switching, but it seems the labels width isn't available at that point. Any ideas for that?^^

Comment: Use an HBox instead of an AnchorPane, then add your left Separator, Label, and right Separator to it (in that order). Make sure you make your three children occupy the space you need; set sizes for your left Separator to ensure it remains constant and have your right Separator occupy the remaining space.

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse. Thanks! :) will update original post with working solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a menu with custom CSS and a TabPane underneath it, below I show you an example made with FXML.

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="382.0" prefWidth="592.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children><MenuButton layoutX="0.37109375" layoutY="1.5" mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
  <items>
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 2" />
  </items>
</MenuButton><MenuButton layoutX="99.0" layoutY="1.5" mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
  <items>
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 2" />
  </items>
</MenuButton><MenuButton layoutX="197.62890625" layoutY="1.5" mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
  <items>
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 2" />
  </items>
</MenuButton><Separator layoutX="2.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="5.0" prefWidth="590.0" /><Pane layoutX="2.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="590.0">
<children><TabPane layoutY="-8.0" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="590.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
  <tabs>
    <Tab text="Start">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="ConvergenceRate1">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab><Tab text="FitneesFunction1">
<content>
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
</content>
</Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
</children></Pane>
</children></Pane>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the options-page has to be a tab (and needs to be for the purpose we need it for). I edited my original post to also more clearly state what i need (the seperator thingy).

Comment: Understood what you meant now. Yes, that is what i want (and i already have that actually), my problem is creating the separators, the ones with "specific options" and "general options" on it.